# How to send variable created in if to elif in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to access a data frame created in an if condition from an elif but getting an error. How do I pass a Data Frame created in if to elif?

```
input:
if df[col].dtype == 'int':
   (some operations)
   df1 = df
elif df[col].dtype == 'obj':
    print(df1.isnull())
```

NameError: name 'df1' is not defined

Comment: you have to define a `df1` before you can use it.

Comment: Define `df1` before `if` statement

Comment: Just put `df1 = None` before your `if` block

Comment: In your `if` clause you do `df1 = df`. This does nothing. You might as well have `print(df.isnull())` in the `else:`.

Comment: @quamrana oops I made a silly mistake thankyou for correcting

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments suggested, just create a variable before the if-block and assign the value in the if block:

```
df1 = None
if df[col].dtype == 'int':
   (some operations)
   df1 = df
elif df[col].dtype == 'obj':
    print(df1.isnull())
```

But even with this code, as mentioned in the other answer, your question doesn't really make sense.

It's impossible to pass data from the if block to the elif block, since the elif block runs, when the if block isn't true. That means it's impossible to pass the data down. If you need to run your elif block when the data is present, you can do this:

```
df1 = None
if df[col].dtype == 'int':
   (some operations)
   df1 = df
if df1 is not None:
   (some other operations)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not make sense. The `elif` is only executed when `if` is not, so you can not access the created variable there.